# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getTypeId() Magento 2.3.0

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, orders, shipping, sales-order

**Show Error after click ship only one product**

[image]

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getTypeId() on null in /var/www/vhosts/xyz.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-inventory-shipping-admin-ui/Model/IsOrderSourceManageable.php:71 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/xyz.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-inventory-shipping-admin-ui/Observer/NewShipmentLoadBefore.php(81): Magento\InventoryShippingAdminUi\Model\IsOrderSourceManageable->execute(Object(Squareup\Omni\Model\Sales\Order\Interceptor)) #1 /var/www/vhosts/xyz.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(72): Magento\InventoryShippingAdminUi\Observer\NewShipmentLoadBefore->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer)) #2 /var/www/vhosts/xyz.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(60): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Magento\InventoryShippingAdminUi\Observer\NewShipmentLoadBefore), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer)) #3 /var/www/vhosts/xyz.com/httpdoc in /var/www/vhosts/xyz.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-inventory-shipping-admin-ui/Model/IsOrderSourceManageable.php on line 71
```

Comment: add your code into question

Comment: Well, can you check if the product you are trying to ship still exists in Magento and it isn't deleted?

Comment: @Tsita Yes i have 5 product in this orders one product are delete screenshot: https://prnt.sc/rfs0ek

Comment: @DineshThakur See my answer for more details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If i get this right then in the following function

```
public function execute(OrderInterface $order): bool
{
    $stocks = $this->stockRepository->getList()->getItems();
    $orderItems = $order->getItems();
    foreach ($orderItems as $orderItem) {
        $productType = $orderItem->getProduct()->getTypeId();
        if (!$this->isSourceItemManagementAllowedForProductType->execute($productType)) {
            continue;
        }

        /** @var StockInterface $stock */
        foreach ($stocks as $stock) {
            $inventoryConfiguration = $this->getStockItemConfiguration->execute(
                $this->getSkuFromOrderItem->execute($orderItem),
                $stock->getStockId()
            );

            if ($inventoryConfiguration->isManageStock()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

You should replace this line by overriding the class in a module.

```
$productType = $orderItem->getProduct()->getTypeId();
```

with this

```
$productType = $orderItem->getProduct() ? $orderItem->getProduct()->getTypeId() : '';
```

The product is possibly deleted and the system is trying to get the type id of a not existing product. 
This part equals to null `$orderItem->getProduct()` in your case.

This has already been fixed in the latest releases of Magento.

Comment: Thankyou tsita its working.

Comment: @DineshThakur You are welcome.

Comment: any idea for this URL: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/307038/error-running-the-setupdicompile-command-magento-2-3-0

Comment: @Tsita it works

Comment: @Tsita, Thanks, it's working